# No .env file found - Nuxt

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I did move my source directory using `srcDir` prop. But when I start my local server console is giving me this error:

`WARN  No .env file found in ~\src nuxt:dotenv 11:19:47`

Have you any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is necessary to specify the path to the .env file via the path option in the dotenv module declaration.

nuxt.config.js

```js
  buildModules: [
    // dotenv
    ['@nuxtjs/dotenv', { path: './' }],
  ],
```